# Parcels disappear when splitting polygons in QField

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, qfield

I have found that when I split polygons using the digitising tools in QField then the neighbouring parcels disappear when the project is synced with QGIS. How can I prevent this?

E.g. I have three neighbouring parcels A, B, C. If I split B horizontally (drawing a line from A across B into C) then B successfully splits. However, when the project is synced with QGIS then A and C disappear and are no longer in the attribute table.

I import/export via cable rather than the cloud.